# JVM Segfaults when installing Matlab Distributed on Rocks CentOS Cluster

Tags: java, matlab, centos, cluster-computing, rocks

At work, I am trying to install Matlab Distributed Computing Server R2011a on a Rocks CentOS Cluster. Following the instructions, I mount the ISO and run ./install &. The installer shows a splash screen but then crashes and outputs the error message below.

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003d39471c7c, pid=29673, tid=1105340736

JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libc.so.6+0x71c7c]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

My boss and I found an article at http://greg.porter.name/wiki/HowTo:MatlabOnRocks by someone who has the exact same problem, but never figured out how to fix it. Has anyone else encountered this problem? If anyone has found a fix, I would be very interested in knowing what steps you took to fix this problem.

Comment: What did MathWorks technical support have to say about this?

Comment: We haven't called them yet. This should probably be our next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a "try to run things on an unsupported platform"-issue.

In this kind of problems, ensure that you do this on a platform explicitly stated to support this combination.  I do not believe that CentOS is a supported Oracle JVM platform.

Comment: That is entirely possible, but unfortunately we cannot avoid using CentOS. We are using the rocks cluster distribution, which uses a modified version of CentOS (and apparently a rather old version, since the default version of python is 2.4!).

Comment: In that case ask MathLab about a version compiled for your system.

Comment: We ended up reverting back to R2010b and it worked. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a general problem of java on memory limits set by cluster manager.
We are encounter this problem with SGE on Fedora Core 13.
see [bug on fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=510344)
Solution is to set limits to ~ 4 Go (not easy all the time ...)
or set environment